# What is the difference between a "barbecue pit" and a "campfire" you can cook food on?

Tags: houston

My friend has a fire pit you can cook on. [It looks kind of like the "SPINDLETOP 45″ FIRE PIT" seen here](https://www.texasoriginalpits.com/product/spindletop-45-fire-pit-copy/).

[image: Fire PIt]

Would it require a permit to use one of these in Houston? Here is the regulation, [HOUSTON FIRE DEPARTMENT LIFE SAFETY BUREAU (LSB) LSB STANDARD 16, REV. 05 OPEN BURNING AND RECREATIONAL FIRES](https://www.houstontx.gov/fire/business/standard16.pdf)

- https://www.houstontx.gov/fire/business/standard16.pdf

The problem is there are two categories in this

- Section 16.3 - Barbecue Pit
- Section 16.6 - Campfire

Because you can always cook campfire, and you can always put a barbecue pit in the center of people for warmth I'm not sure which way this would go? Can you have a barbecue pit that you're burning logs in for warmth that is not a camp fire for the purpose of needing a permit?

Comment: It seems that the definitions are more about purpose than physical form.  Keep some food nearby to legitimize your case that it’s a BBQ if you expect any inspectors to challenge you and have at it.  Or just get a permit if you don’t want any risk of controversy.

Answer (score 1):

### Look at the definitions

> 16.2.1 Open Burning.
>
> Open burning’, for the purpose of this standard is the burning of: a bonfire, rubbish fire, campfire, trench fire, or other fire in an outdoor location where fuel being burned is not contained in an approved incinerator, outdoor fireplace, barbecue grill or barbecue pit.

This is an "outdoor fireplace" and not a "campfire".

Comment: That's not defining an "outdoor fireplace". It's just using the term. Look at the pictures for that on google. https://www.google.com/search?q=outdoor+fireplace Moreover, the definition of a campfire says _"The campfire shall be contained in a metal container not to exceed 60 inches by 60
inches and the sides not less than 15 inches high."_ What does the metal containment for a campfire look like if not exactly the picture I showed above?

Comment: @EvanCarroll a fire pit has a distinct lack of a grill